# Sort 2D array elements in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Say I have a 2D array of n length, is there a way I can sort the 2D array in descending order according to the size of the sub-array

For example:

```
{{"1","b","g"},{"e","3"},{"r","2","9","a"},{"2"}}
```

would become:

```
{{"r","2","9","a"},{"1","b","g"},{"e","3"},{"2"}}
```

Comment: There is no much difference from sorting 1D array of numbers. You can use array.length.
Sorted array in your example is in ascending order, not descending.

Answer (score 0):

```
String tab[][] = new String[][]{{"1","b","g"},{"e","3"},{"r","2","9","a"},{"2"}};
String temp[];          
    for (int i = 0; i <tab.length; i++) {     
        for (int j = i+1; j <tab.length; j++) {     
            if(tab[i].length < tab[j].length) {
               temp = tab[i];    
               tab[i] = tab[j];    
               tab[j] = temp;    
             }     
          }     
      }             
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tab));
```

output: `[[r, 2, 9, a], [1, b, g], [e, 3], [2]]`

Answer (score -1):

More details are required on this question.

Considering that the given data structure is an array it would look like -

```
[["1","b","g"],["e","3"],["r","2","9","a"],["2"]]
```

To sort this array in python consider the below given code :-

```
a = [["1","b","g"],["e","3"],["r","2","9","a"],["2"]]
a.sort(key=len)
```

It will sort the array according to the length of subarrays

Comment: Question is tagged java